# Running .NET core App on .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I was reading this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/ about using different monikers for .NET core app and I was wondering what is the difference between creating ConsoleApp with .NET framework 4.5.1 and creating ConsoleApp .NET core with moniker set to .net framework 4.5.1.

Is it expected to have any differences in behavior? The only difference I can think of is that the first one will use csproj and the second one will use xproj (ok xproj is deprecated now, so new csproj format). I'm asking this question because my current app is built on top of .NET framework 4.5.1 and I was thinking of migrating it to .NET core on top of .NET framework.

Comment: The second one will soon use csproj as well after .NET Core SDK 1.0 release.

Comment: @LexLi yes, I mentioned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the project.json build tools the ".NET Core SDK" was only partially true: the tools can be used to build for runtimes other than .NET Core, i.e. .NET Framework.  A console app built for .NET Framework using project.json is exactly the same as a console app built for .NET Framework using csproj.

The new csproj format tries to correct this common mixup. You'll notice in VS 2017, projects use the ".NET SDK", aka "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" (dropped Core from the name). This new SDK can be used to build .NET Framework, .NET Standard, and .NET Core projects.