# Running a .Net Core app with .Net Framework

Tags: .net

IS this possible to run a .net core application on a machine which has .net framework only and no .net core installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running .NET core App on .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415443/running-net-core-app-on-net-framework)

Comment: The idea behind of dotnet Core is remove the dependency of a preinstaled Framework, and let the applications run in a stand alone scenario, but if you want to Biuld a dotnet Core app you need to install dotnet Core framework.

Comment: @eduCan, Underestood that, but can I build a .net core application and run it in a windows OS that has .net framework installed only?